# Application Slowdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

I'm trying to use apache bench to benchmark my application and I'm getting "interesting" results

Watching the logs from my application and the output from apache bench it seems that there is a large discrepency.  I was chalking it up to network latency, but the discrepency is still there when benchmarking "localhost".

How can I determine where the lag is as it seems to be non network based and not based on my code.

AB Reports

```
Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0    0   0.6      0       2
Processing:   849 1353 511.1   1247    3233
Waiting:      848 1353 511.1   1247    3233
Total:        850 1353 511.4   1247    3235

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%   1247
  66%   1329
  75%   1497
  80%   1595
  90%   1890
  95%   3235
  98%   3235
  99%   3235
 100%   3235 (longest request)
```

The Application Logs

```
0.457508658971436
0.487119069125137
0.64489275544097
0.308814075251248
0.347146275286174
0.413624988232478
0.346384754750842
0.440318102805972
0.383319550604894
0.501201249649599
0.546330090455061
0.324228916712541
0.503295781085244
0.258641210789654
0.419751448936304
0.344909658677117
0.368373660208557
0.391326015130321
0.408486124472911
0.432033417312903
0.841326557573717
0.380724921354457
0.982096568223106
0.988279723010904
0.477995521167366
0.553187274907863
0.604180103806168
0.605961767889521
0.5603846238645
0.469985557007126
0.602743853678869
0.613931136285929
0.518576586533195
0.589374548765836
0.541912501430476
0.56989243172475
0.516491854075027
0.409568911484087
0.245887841603729
3.22576074186659
```

My Code

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var fullTimer = new utilities.HiPerfTimer();
        fullTimer.Start();
        // CUSTOM CODE WENT HERE
        fullTimer.Stop();
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(fullTimer.Duration);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely be looking at something like a profiler. I've used [Redgate's ANTs performance profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) to test some code of mine that was running slowly. Even though I thought the code was pretty straight forward, it showed me that one line was attributing for 48% of execution time.

There are plenty of other performance profilers around too, and you can use the free trial periods to get an immediate indication of what is causing the slowdown.